# jQuery not working when I load dynamic component in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have implemented dynamic components in Angular and whenever a dynamic component is loaded its corresponding jQuery is not working. Same jQuery script is working elsewhere.

This is where my dynamic component loads:

```
<div class="listing-table-outer" [@myAwesomeAnimation]='state'>
      <app-dynamic-question [componentData]="componentData"></app-dynamic-question>
    </div>
```

Below html will be loaded dynamically.

```
<div class="panel panel-default " >
    <div class="panel-body" >
     <h1>{{textLabel}}</h1>
        <p>{{textHeader}}</p>

        <div class="form-inline display-one" role="form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="learn-more magtop10">
            <a> <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i> Learn More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="display_advance">
            <div class="well">
                <p>{{textFooter}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bs-component">
            <a href="#" class="btn panel-theme-clearbutton btn-lg" *ngIf="this.showButton[0].txt_button == 'Clear'">Clear</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn panel-theme-clearbutton btn-lg" *ngIf="this.showButton[1].txt_button == 'Skip'">Skip</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn panel-theme-button btn-lg" *ngIf="this.showButton[2].txt_button == 'Continue'">Continue</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have written this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.learn-more').click(function() {

    $('.display_advance').slideToggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass(" glyphicon-play glyphicon-triangle-bottom");
});


});
```

I have checked this script and it is working perfectly elsewhere.

Please let me know why this is happening.

Comment: Use `$(document).on("click", ".learn-more", function () {...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already stated yourself, the html is loaded dynamically. That means that this html is not yet there when `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` is executed. So you're trying to add a click event to an element that doesn't exist at that moment.
For this exact situation there's a thing called event delegation.

Instead of doing

```
$('.learn-more').on('click', function() { ... });
```

you would do

```
$(document).on('click', '.learn-more', function() { ... });
```

This way any elements below `document` with class `learn-more`, now or in the future, will get this click event.