# jquery plugin working only when angular component is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm new to jQuery, and turns out that I need to use this plugin http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/ in my angular project.

I can see it working the first time the component is created, but once the component is destroyed and created again it does not work.

```
 <div class="row shop-list" *ngIf="data && data.names.length > 0">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table [ngClass]="{'header-fixed': headerFixed}" class="table table-striped table-borderless">
    ....
    </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```

As you can see, my resizable table will only be shown if the data object contains some names.

In my component.ts file I have the following.

```
 @Input('data') data: mockData;
```

and

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if (changes.data.currentValue) {
     this.data = changes.data.currentValue;
     setTimeout(() => {
       (<any>jQuery('table[class="table table-striped table-borderless"]')).colResizable({
       liveDrag: true,
       hoverCursor: 'col-resize',
       dragCursor: 'col-resize',
       minWidth: 114,
       });
     });
   }
 }
```

Given this my problem is the one commented in the start. If I enter the page I can see the resizable table work correctly, but if I go back and then re-enter the page the table is not resizable and even the cursor is not changing. Even if I don't leave the page but I change the data values and give it an empty value so that the table is not shown, and then give it some values so that it should be shown, it appears, but again, not resizable.

I think that this problem is related to the fact that component is loaded dynamically, and there might not be any table element when jquery code is executed, as I've read here [jQuery not working when I load dynamic component in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907504/jquery-not-working-when-i-load-dynamic-component-in-angular), 
but I do not know how to apply that to my question.

Some help would be appreciated, I'm quite lost here.